# Strangely similar download count on NuGet.org

Tags: nuget

I have a package published on NuGet.org that is getting a strange number of download for each version. It is mostly between 25 and 30 downloads, no matter how closely two version were released.

Is there a bot-system on NuGet that will download packages for any reason, or are these organic downloads ? I didn't really expect anyone to download any of it since it's mostly a very small and barely useful library at this point, mostly destined to my own usage ...

[image]

Is there an explanation for this oddly homogeneous distribution ?

Comment: It's quite possible that there are some web crawlers downloading your package. Or maybe you have just about 30 people using and updating your package.

Comment: The webcrawler thing sounds far more likely ... I don't see how 30 people would need this package so much they update it in a matter of days after each release ... and they don't even skip releases (some of them being 10mn appart because i'm a bad dev that let bugs through)

Comment: Well in that case: Here's my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite possible some webcrawlers downloading your package.